# React without npm - is it possible to import libraries / modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am using React without npm (owing to serverside restrictions). In my `<head>` tag I've got the following

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.4.2/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.4.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.js"></script>
```

And my react code is packaged inside a `text/babel` script tag and works perfectly. Simplified example:

```
<script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );    
</script>
```

I would like to use an external module for charting. However, if I use https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs (just downloading it and serving it locally), by including

either

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/react-chartjs/chart.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/babel" src="/js/react-chartjs/chart.js"></script>
```

throws an error:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

presumably because `require` is an npm command. I've tried using require.js but again, that throws errors. Similarly, if I serve the javascript version of chart.js from

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js
```

and within my `text/babel` script tag try to include the library with any of

```
// Using CommonJS
var Chart = require('chart.js')
var myChart = new Chart({...})

// ES6
import Chart from 'chart.js'
let myChart = new Chart({...})

// Using requirejs
require(['path/to/Chartjs'], function(Chart){
 var myChart = new Chart({...})
})
```

It also throws errors. Is there a way to import plain javascript libraries or react modules when using react without npm?

Comment: Try including this one in your project. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-chartjs/0.8.0/react-chartjs.js

Comment: ouch no npm? could you elaborate on this restriction? that's a major crutch for any kind of client side development post 2015

Comment: @azium so does that mean it's not possible at all? I mean we could use the code without compiling is faster. In my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is a HORRIBLE hack using PHP but it's the only option I found. I too do not have a server with npm available. So, instead of using javascript import, or package managers, like browserify, which DO NOT work as they still require npm, I use PHP to create a single large contents of  from multiple files:

```
<script type="text/babel">

<?php

include 'BDRMLElement.js';

?>

...

class App extends React.Component {
 ...
 render() {
   return (
        <div>
          <BDRMLElement />
...

</script>
```

Comment: Does it work til now? Why it's different than using text/babel? I really want to know.